# Prevent downloading, printing and copy/paste for External Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-users

Is there a setting inside SharePoint or Office 365 which grant external users access to SharePoint but prevents them:

1. Downloading and
2. Printing Documents
3. Copy/paste functionality

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict downloads with Sharepoint Group management and assignment of the Restricted View privilege. It prevents Downloading documents and printing them(but keep in mind that nothing stops you from screenshoting the monitor view and printing the screenshot)

Unfortunately, Printing and Copy/pasting are procedures handled by the browser, which means that specially customized JS scripts will have to be in place, which in addition, we couldn't know what kind of perfomance issue might occur(if any).

Comment: but if you have Read-Only, you can download !!

Comment: sorry about that, i meant restricted view:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/07/sharepoint-online-disable-download-option-for-documents.html#:~:text=To%20disable%20the%20download%20option%20in%20SharePoint%20Online%2C%20you%20can,library%20where%20you%20grant%20permissions.

Comment: but in this case we will need to set this on each site, i am asking about a global settings which apply to all the sites..

Comment: Okay, then you should rephrase the question.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/deploy-file-collaboration#manage-access
As you can read from the above link, what you are asking is probably possible with Device management, which goes outside the plane of SP and requires Premium Azure AD. 
I would like to stress out the fact that there might not be a similar setting for External Users, but you should try it out since Conditional Access is applicable to these User Groups.

Comment: Restricted view also prevent editing. How could you set it up so a document can be viewed and edited by users with access, but also set so they can't download (and only can view/edit Office docs online).